# Why does python's requests module give a different latency measurement to ping?

Tags: python, rest, api, ubuntu, networking

I want to know what my latency is when im communicating to an API. I think there are two ways to measure this:

Firstly, I can make a get request and measure the elapsed time in seconds:

```
import requests
response = requests.get("http://api.mywebsite.com")
response.elapsed.total_seconds()
```

This method gives times around 0.014271 seconds.

Alternatively, I can just ping it, it returns values like:

```
64 bytes from xx.xxx.xx.xx: icmp_seq=1 ttl=52 time=2.99 ms
```

...

```
12 packets transmitted, 12 received, 0% packet loss, time 11012ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 2.992/3.051/3.098/0.046 ms
```

Why are the measurements different at 14ms and 3ms? Which one reflects the time it takes for a restful api request to return a response?

Comment: The latency is, how long it takes in your code, isn't it?

Comment: shouldn't the elapsed time and the ping time be the same though?

Comment: Do they do the same?

Comment: they're both making a request to the server and seeing how long it takes to receive a response.

Comment: No, that's not true. There are fundamental differences between a ping and an HTTP request.

Comment: Ping measures ICMP latency (uses ICMP echo), and ICMP is an integral part of IP in the network layer, but HTTP is in the application layer, so it requires more processing.